# How can I add a custom column menu tab in ag-grid?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Is there a way to add a custom column menu tab with my own favourite icon which on click would render my custom react component?

something like

```
myColDef.menuTabs: ['generalMenuTab', 'filterMenuTab', 'myCustomMenuTab']
```

FYI I'm using v12.0.2

Comment: btw on this doc page https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-menu/?framework=react#gsc.tab=0

the gibberishMenuTab of the gold column throw an exception!

Answer (score 2):

What you're after can't be done I'm afraid. The grid supports React components in all sorts of ways (renderers, editors, filters etc), but not via the column menu.

I've updated the docs page to remove the gibberish issue - it'll be fixed properly in the next release, thanks for highlighting this.

Comment: Is that something you're planning to add in future version?

Comment: Hi - I know its something on our todo list, but I don't think it's something we're targeting in the short to medium term I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

This would be helpful to have. In particular for us, we'd like to filter based off row properties, and not row values. Creating our own tab to filter by cell colors that we have assigned with our own set of labels would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that it would be a nice feature to have. Apparently, there's no quick out-of-the-box solution to do it. The only workaround I see is to implement your own [custom Header component](https://ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/component-header/) which would display any buttons your want.

There you can put a button to open your own custom menu, which you can implement as any regular UI component. It also means you'll need to manually implement all standard menu options that Ag-Grid provides out of the box if you need them.